# StartActivity(intent) does not seem to work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

In my AndroidManifest.xml I have a MainActivity and a ItemInfoActivity.

```
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
        
        <activity android:name=".ItemInfoActivity">
        </activity>
```

In a Fragment of MainActivity, I have a callback that calls the following when a button is pressed

```
val intent = Intent(requireContext(),ItemInfoActivity::class.java)
Log.d("ItemLookupFragment","itemId = $itemId")
startActivity(intent)
```

Below is the ItemInfoActivity class

```
class ItemInfoActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding : ActivityItemInfoBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        Log.d("ItemInfoActivity","onCreate")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        binding = ActivityItemInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
    }
}
```

However when button is pressed the app goes to a blank screen and not to the expected activity.

Android Studio logcat shows that the log above does indeed get called. Profiler shows that the current activity running is ItemInfoActivity.

However the screen is blank, logs I put in the ItemInfoActivity are not called. The only remotely related log is `Expecting binder but got null!`

Have I missed something?

Comment: have you bind view with activity in ItemInfoActivity?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with ItemInfoActivity class

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the view for your ***ItemInfoActivity***

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_info)
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with ItemInfoActivity class